# How to run mobile browser tests in android using wdio appium?

Tags: javascript, android-emulator, mocha.js, webdriver-io, appium-android

I am trying to run a basic test in Android chrome browser for my mobile based web application with appium WebdriverIO, but getting following error upon running a command. Am I missing something?

I am using android emulator here.

Here is the complete logs of test run.

```
PS C:\vyu_web_wdio\webdriverio-appium-v8> npx wdio wdio.conf.js      

Execution of 1 workers started at 2023-05-12T05:51:10.128Z

2023-05-12T05:51:10.217Z INFO chromedriver: Initiate Chromedriver Launcher (v8.1.1)
2023-05-12T05:51:10.218Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2023-05-12T05:51:10.237Z INFO chromedriver: Start Chromedriver (C:\vyu_web_wdio\webdriverio-appium-v8\node_modules\chromedriver\lib\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe) with args --port=9515 --url-base=/
2023-05-12T05:51:10.282Z INFO chromedriver: Starting ChromeDriver 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae5bf128b1bd8f4d627c8cbd55f70c-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#912}) on port 9515
2023-05-12T05:51:10.283Z INFO chromedriver: Only local connections are allowed.
2023-05-12T05:51:10.283Z INFO chromedriver: Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
2023-05-12T05:51:10.291Z INFO chromedriver: ChromeDriver was started successfully.
2023-05-12T05:51:16.327Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2023-05-12T05:51:16.329Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: wdio.conf.js
[0-0] 2023-05-12T05:51:17.605Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] RUNNING in Chrome - file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/src/test/specs/vyu_web.spec.js
[0-0] 2023-05-12T05:51:17.813Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
[0-0] 2023-05-12T05:51:17.968Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:9515/session
[0-0] 2023-05-12T05:51:17.968Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: {
[0-0]       platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]       'appium:platformVersion': '11.0',
[0-0]       'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel 3 API 30',
[0-0]       browserName: 'Chrome',
[0-0]       acceptInsecureCerts: true
[0-0]     },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     platformName: 'Android',
[0-0]     'appium:platformVersion': '11.0',
[0-0]     'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel 3 API 30',
[0-0]     browserName: 'Chrome',
[0-0]     acceptInsecureCerts: true
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2023-05-12T05:51:18.006Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to session not created: session not created: No matching capabilities found
[0-0] 2023-05-12T05:51:18.006Z ERROR webdriver: session not created: session not created: No matching capabilities found
[0-0]     at getErrorFromResponseBody (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:194:12)
[0-0]     at NodeJSRequest._request (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/webdriver/build/request/index.js:164:23)   
[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[0-0]     at async startWebDriverSession (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:63:20)       
[0-0]     at async Function.newSession (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:24:45)
[0-0]     at async remote (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:48:22)
[0-0]     at async Runner._startSession (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:221:29)    
[0-0]     at async Runner._initSession (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:187:25)     
[0-0]     at async Runner.run (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:77:19)
[0-0] 2023-05-12T05:51:18.013Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
[0-0] session not created: No matching capabilities found
[0-0]     at startWebDriverSession (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:68:15)
[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[0-0]     at async Function.newSession (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:24:45)
[0-0]     at async remote (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:48:22)
[0-0]     at async Runner._startSession (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:221:29)    
[0-0]     at async Runner._initSession (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:187:25)     
[0-0]     at async Runner.run (file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:77:19)
[0-0] FAILED in Chrome - file:///C:/vyu_web_wdio/webdriverio-appium-v8/src/test/specs/vyu_web.spec.js
2023-05-12T05:51:18.140Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2023-05-12T05:51:18.141Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:08

2023-05-12T05:51:18.146Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2023-05-12T05:51:18.398Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2023-05-12T05:51:18.399Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
```

Here is my wdio.conf.js file,

```
exports.config = {


    runner: 'local',
    
    port: 4723,
    specs: [
        './src/test/specs/**/vyu_web.spec.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],

    maxInstances: 10,
    
    capabilities: [
        {
            platformName: 'Android',
            "appium:platformVersion": '11.0',
            "appium:deviceName": 'Pixel 3 API 30',
            browserName: 'Chrome',
            acceptInsecureCerts: true // accepts all SSL certificates
        }
    ],
    
    logLevel: 'info',

    bail: 0,
    
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    
    waitforTimeout: 12000,
    
    connectionRetryTimeout: 60000,
    
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    
    services: ['appium', 'chromedriver'],
    
    framework: 'mocha',
    
    reporters: ['spec'],

    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 999999
    },
}
```

This is my spec file

```
describe('Android chrome browser test', () => {
    it('Should open google chrome in android and perform these steps', async () => {
        await browser.url("https://www.google.com")

        const input = await $('input[type="text"]')

        await input.setValue('Appium WDIO');

        await browser.keys('\uE007'); // Press Enter

        const title = await browser.getTitle();
        
        console.log('Page title:', title);
    })
})
```